# SQL Server : With Syntax

Tags: sql-server, paging

I have a table of `employeeSomething`

tb_EmployeeSomething

```
EmpID| TypeID
1 | 1
1 | 1
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 2
2 | 2
2 | 2
2 | 2
```

Now I'm using paging in my program and the return must be

```
EmpID| TypeID| RowNum
1|1|1
1|2|2
2|2|3
```

Here what I've tried

```
Declare @start int
Declare @end int

With Tmp2 as (
    With Tmp1 as (
        Select Distinct EmpID, TypeID 
        From tb_deductionBalance
    )
    Select *, row_number() OVER ( order by employeeID ) as RowNum 
    From Tmp1
)
Select * From Tmp2
Where RowNum Between @Start and @End
```

I'm not sure if there a better way to do this.

Sorry for my English.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ? Also a similar question [SQL Server select rows between two values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481002/sql-server-select-rows-between-two-values)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty - shouldn't code review only be used for code that actually works? This code is broken because they're attempting to nest CTEs (admittedly, the question would be better if they provided the **error message**)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Oh by reading the question my impression was it is working and he need to improve :) that's why I suggested the code-review !!

Comment: Actually my code above doesn't work. Sorry I didn't post the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't nest [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)s (CTEs), you comma separate them:

```
;With Tmp1 as (
        Select Distinct EmpID, TypeID 
        From tb_deductionBalance
), Tmp2 as (
    Select *,
       row_number() OVER ( order by empID /* no employeeID in Tmp1 */) as RowNum 
    From Tmp1
)
Select * From Tmp2
Where RowNum Between @Start and @End
```

Any CTE may reference any earlier CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER() function to do it.
You can find information about ROW_NUMBER here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx